# VirtualQueryEx alternative for Linux - how to get virtual memory range of another process

Tags: c++, c, linux, winapi, memory-management

I went through [this blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx) and [this videocast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRPMdb1YMS8). In Windows if I want to retrieve information about a range of pages within the virtual address space of a specified process, I can use WinAPI `VirtualQueryEx` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION meminfo;
unsigned char *addr = 0;
for(;;)
{
    if(!VirtualQueryEx(hProc, addr, &meminfo, sizeof(meminfo)))
        break;
    if(meminfo.State & MEM_COMMIT)
    {
        //collect some data from meminfo
    }
    addr = (unsigned char*)meminfo.BaseAddress + meminfo.RegionSize;
}
```

I wondered how to get similar set of information in Linux using syscalls, but it is not clear for me how using C/C++ can I gather such a data under Linux. I went through [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux) when there are suggestions to take a look at `/proc/<pid>/mem` or `/proc/<pid>/maps` files. Is it the good direction? How should look the closest implementation to this one provided here, but for Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `proc` filesystem is part of the Linux API, so this is the way to go. A lot of data in that filesystem is usually accessed using a library wrapper, but that's where the data lie.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `/proc/<pid>/maps` is the only reliable and supported way to do it. Even [`libunwind` is using it](https://github.com/bgirard/libunwind/blob/master/src/dl-iterate-phdr.c):

```
  if (maps_init (&mi, getpid()) < 0)
    return -1;

  unsigned long offset;
  while (maps_next (&mi, &low, &hi, &offset)) {
    struct dl_phdr_info info;
    info.dlpi_name = mi.path;
    info.dlpi_addr = low;
```